# How can I redirect to login page when surfing to /login via routes ? C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to be able to go to the login page by just going to `websiteBaseAddress/login` - how do I do this with routes in C# using ASP.NET MVC if possible? I work with Identity that has its own area btw.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AuthorizeAttribute` class:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to the login page
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply the attribute to your controller or action:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class YourController : Controller
{
    // Your controller actions
}
```

If needed apply the attribute to a specific action method:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // Your action logic
    }
}
```

Configure your routes in StartUp.cs:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Login",
        url: "Account/Login",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
    );

// Other routes...
```

Comment: I really just want to hide the login view. I want the only way to go to the login view to be to surf to /login. Do I really need a controller for this?

Comment: Yeah I think you should.